# Convexity of an inner product value function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Let the function $g : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be such that each of its elements $g_i$ is strictly convex, and let $f : \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^m \times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by

$$ f (x,y) := y^\top g(x),$$

Consider the value function

$$ v(y) = \min_{x\in C(y)} f(x,y),$$

where $C(y)$ is compact, and $C$ is convex in the sense that for any $0\leq\lambda\leq 1$, and $y,y'\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$, we have that $x\in C(y)$ and $x'\in C(y')$ implies
$$
\lambda x+(1-\lambda)x' \in C(\lambda y+(1-\lambda)y').
$$
I would like to show that $v$ is convex.

I have shown the result in a special case where $g(x)=x^\top Gx$ with $G$ positive definite and for a specific $C(y)$ but I'm hoping that it holds more generally.

EDIT: I have updated the notion of convexity for $C$. See Hans Engler's response below.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: You can use `{\Bbb R}` instead. Use `\to` for $\to$

Comment: What is a convex vector field?

Comment: Where does this come from?

Comment: You mean $g$ has components which are convex functions, right? Otherwise this makes no sense.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes thanks for the edit. I’m not sure what your question about convex vector field is about.

Comment: @V.S.e.H. No I mean the whole function is convex. Not component by component.

Comment: @user_lambda The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) of convex function uses $\leq$. However, ${\Bbb R}^n$ has no $\leq$.  In order-theoretic terms, total order versus partial order, or something along those lines.

Comment: What Rodrigo said basically, what is your definition of convexity for $g$, or more specifically what order relation are you using? Is it wrt a convex cone $K$, s.t. $x\geq_K y \iff x-y\in K$? In case of component-wise convexity then $K = \mathbb{R}^n_+$.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry I misunderstood your comments. Indeed, I meant to say that $g_i$ is strictly convex for all $i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f(x,y)$ is jointly convex in $x,y$ and continuous then,
By jointly convex, we mean,
$$f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2,\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2) \leq \lambda f(x_1,y_1) + (1-\lambda) f(x_2,y_2)$$

Let $$v(y_1) = \min_{x \in C(y_1)} f(x,y_1) = f(x_1,y_1)$$
$$v(y_2) = \min_{x \in C(y_2)} f(x,y_2) = f(x_2,y_2)$$
$$v(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2) = \min_{x \in C(\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2)} f(x,\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2) \leq f(\lambda x_1 + (1-\lambda) x_2,\lambda y_1 + (1-\lambda) y_2) \leq \lambda f(x_1,y_1) + (1-\lambda) f(x_2,y_2) = \lambda v(y_1) + (1-\lambda) v(y_2)$$

Hence $v(.)$ is convex if $f(x,y)$ is jointly convex and continuous.

Joint convexity is also necessary, since we can assign $C(y_1)=\{x_1\}$ and $C(y_2)=\{x_2\}$ and this assignment forces convexity property of $v(y)$ to imply $f(x,y)$ to be jointly convex w.r.t $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ and this assignment is completely arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks! To make sure I understand, the last part of your answer shows that there is a set $C(y)$ such that the convexity of $f$ is necessary. There could be other sets such that $f$ is not convex but $v$ is. Right?

Comment: Yes. You need to add more constraints on $C(y)$. As such you can use this definition of $C(y)$ and force joint convexity on $f(x,y)$

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be correct in any sense unless you make some assumptions on how $C(y)$ depends on $y$. For a counterexample, consider the 1-dim case with
$$
g(x) = x^2, \; f(x,y) = x^2y\; \text{for}\; x,  y \ge 0,  \quad C(y) = \begin{cases} [1,2] \quad (y \in \mathbb{Q}) \\
[3,4] \quad (y \notin \mathbb{Q})
\end{cases}
$$
Then $v(y) = y$ if $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $v(y) = 9y$ if $y \notin \mathbb{Q}$, which is certainly not a convex function of $y$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had a different notion of convexity for $C$ in mind but did not write it down properly. I have updated the question.